# MappingException was unhandled: NHibernate

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, nhibernate, c#-4.0

I am trying to learn about NHibernate from the book [NHibernate in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394923) and trying to compile and run the first example is giving me the following exception:

> ```
> Could not compile the mapping document:
> ```
>
> Namespace.FolderName.ClassName.hbm.xml

The inner exception is

```
{"<hibernate-mapping xmlns='urn:hibernate-mapping-2.2'> was not expected."}
```

Here's my mapping file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:hibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   auto-import="true">
  <class name="Namespace.Folder.ClassName,Namespace.Folder" lazy="false">
    <id name="id" access="field">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" access="field" column="name"/>
    <many-to-one access="field" name="manager" column="manager"
                 cascade="all"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This happens when I am trying to create a session as follows:

```
static ISession OpenSession()
        {
            if (factory == null)
            {
                Configuration c = new Configuration();
                c.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
                factory = c.BuildSessionFactory();
            }
            return factory.OpenSession();
        }
```

The exception is raised by the following line:

```
c.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
```

Here's the entire exception stack trace:

**

> NHibernate.MappingException was
>   unhandled   Message=Could not compile
>   the mapping document:
>   DataGenerator.HibernateMapper.Individual.hbm.xml
>   Source=NHibernate   StackTrace:
>          at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.LogAndThrow(Exception
>   exception) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line
>   340
>          at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.LoadMappingDocument(XmlReader
>   hbmReader, String name) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line
>   1783
>          at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddXmlReader(XmlReader
>   hbmReader, String name) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line
>   1813
>          at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddInputStream(Stream
>   xmlInputStream, String name) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line
>   630
>          at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddResource(String
>   path, Assembly assembly) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line
>   668
>          at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddAssembly(Assembly
>   assembly) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line
>   761
>          at DataGenerator.Program.OpenSession() in
>   C:\Documents and
>   Settings\user1\Desktop\DataGeneration\DataGenerator\DataGenerator\Program.cs:line
>   46
>          at DataGenerator.Program.CreateIndividualAndSaveToDatabase()
>   in C:\Documents and
>   Settings\user1\Desktop\DataGeneration\DataGenerator\DataGenerator\Program.cs:line
>   29
>          at DataGenerator.Program.Main() in C:\Documents and
>   Settings\user1\Desktop\DataGeneration\DataGenerator\DataGenerator\Program.cs:line
>   16
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly
>   assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String
>   assemblyFile, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object
>   state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>   InnerException:
>   System.InvalidOperationException
>          Message=There is an error in XML document (1, 2).
>          Source=System.Xml
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader
>   xmlReader, String encodingStyle,
>   XmlDeserializationEvents events)
>               at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader
>   textReader)
>               at NHibernate.Cfg.NamedXmlDocument..ctor(String
>   name, XmlDocument document) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\NamedXmlDocument.cs:line
>   27
>               at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.LoadMappingDocument(XmlReader
>   hbmReader, String name) in
>   d:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:line
>   1774
>          InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
>               Message= was
>   not expected.
>               Source=2p514b3b
>               StackTrace:
>                    at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderHbmMapping.Read109_hibernatemapping()
>               InnerException:

**

Can somebody give me some pointers on whats going on here?

Thanks

Comment: @downvoter - Care to explain why?

Comment: @sc_ray ( I'm not the downvoter :) ) you should have something more in the exception message explaining why it can't compile:check the InnerException too.

Comment: @Felice Pollano - I will paste a detailed exception message. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Felice Pollano - I pasted the inner exception. I am not sure if I should be using some other value besides 2.2?

Comment: Can you show us your mapping file?

Comment: @Yads - Sure. I have added the mapping file to my post.

Comment: See the edit to my answer -- a missing "n" may be the cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that the mapping file's build action is set to "Embedded resource".

EDIT:

Try

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true">
```

Note the **n** in nhibernate.

Comment: Thanks. The build action for the mapping file is set as an Embedded Resource, it is still throwing this exception.

Comment: It should be already "Embedded Resource" since he receive the exception. If not no exception at all happens.